# Link JIRA and Bitbucket

Tags: jira

I followed the instructions to integrate JIRA and BitBucket. 
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/AOD/Linking+a+bitbucket+or+GitHub+repository+with+JIRA+OnDemand

I created a new project in JIRA and then added multiple Issues, version and components. After I enabled the integration, no issues,components or versions appear in Bitbucket. Repo in Bitbucket was created yesterday.

Was is the expected behavior?

**BitBucket** - Private issue tracker
**BitBucket** - OAuthConsumer configured:

JIRA DVCS is configured. URL is empty, is this a problem?

**BitBucket** - Integrated Applications: JIRA DVCS and Jira Importer Plugin

**JIRA** -  Smart Commits is enabled in my repository

Comment: I have the same problem https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/267981/bitbucket-issues-doesn-t-appear-in-jira

Comment: You need to make sure you configured application links on both bitbukcet and JIRA. I got the similar issue but later i was able to clone and push from jira to BB.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add bitbucket in Jira>System>Application Navigator? Can you switch to bitbucket?

You need to add account as Host:Bitbucket Jira>Add-on>DVCS Accounts:
Host: Bitbucket
Team or User Account
OAuthKey
OAuthSecret

If you like to auto link your new repos and enable smart commits, check out
Auto link new repositories
Enable Smart Commits

Your repositories will be synched after you complete this configuration.

We are also using Jira On Demand and we have no issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Application Links** in *Bitbucket* which creates everything needed for the communication with Jira. (OAuth access token in the DVCS)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[Here](https://mibexsoftware.com/2015/11/13/how-to-use-oauth-with-atlassian-products/) is explained in detail.

Answer (score 0):

This is announced now as a new Atlassian product:

[JIRA Software and Bitbucket](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/bitbucket-integration)